# What is the remainder when $N = (1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + ........... + 1000! )^{40}$ is divided by $10?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, factorial

> What is the remainder when $N = (1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + ........... + 1000!  )^{40}$  is divided by $10$ ?

**My try:**

On watching the pattern as it grows, after $4!$ all are divisible by $10$.

So, infact I am just left with $N = (1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 0)^{40}$ and I need to check the remainder when this $N$ is divisible by $10$.

Hence, the $N$ sums up to $33^{40}$ when divided by $10$ .

Now, after this I can simply apply Euler's Theorem such that

$33^{4} = 1 (mod 10)$

After all, the remainder comes out to be $1$.

---

I don't have an answer for this. Is my understanding right or did I miss something?

Comment: $33=3\bmod{10}$ and $3^2=-1\bmod{10}$ hence $3^{12}=(-1)^4=1\bmod{10}$ and $33^{12}=3^{12}=1\bmod{10}$

Comment: @Did, So, 1 is right ?

Comment: One issue, $33^9 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 10$ - the exponent you are looking for is $\phi(10)=4$ because $10$ is not prime (and so it's Euler's theorem not Fermat's Little Theorem). But the answer comes out as $1$ (even more simply), nevertheless.

Comment: "I guess after 4! all are divisible by 10."  Don't guess.  Know.  If $n \ge 5$ then $5|n!$ and $2|n!$ so $10|n!$.  No guessing at all.

Comment: @Joffan Thanks it was a typo !!

Comment: ...and $3^2=-1\bmod{10}$ hence $3^{40}=(-1)^{20}=1\bmod{10}$ and $N=33^{40}=3^{40}=1\bmod{10}$. (Sorry for the previous typo, dunno why $40$ became $12$...)

Comment: @Did what is the significance of 12?

Comment: @fleablood See previous comment. (Aren't you coming a little late?)

Comment: Hmmm.... somehow the the typo comment wasn't visible when I made my comment.  Or I blindly didn't see it.  (Actually when on a page, my web browser doesn't update comments as I watch, so I guess your correction comment hadn't posted when I came to the page and when I posted my comment 6 minutes after you made it, it wasn't visible on my viewing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct. A few pointers, however:

1. Note that you can reduce $33$ to just $3$
2. Euler's theorem says that $3^{4}\equiv 1\pmod{10}$

Comment: Sorry, That was a typo :)

Comment: Euler's theorem also says that $\gcd(33,10)=1\implies33^{\phi(10)}\equiv1\pmod{10}\implies33^4\equiv1\pmod{10}$

Comment: @barakmanos After applying 1., that is exactly what 2. says in my answer.

Comment: What I meant to say is that you could get rid of #1 and still use Euler's theorem as is.

Comment: @barakmanos That is true. But why would you not want to reduce modulo $10$ when that's so easy to do?

Comment: So is deducing that $\gcd(10,33)=1$... Anyways, I just thought it might be worth noting the fact that the stage of reducing $33$ to $3$ is redundant, since both are coprime to $10$ hence "valid" for Euler's theorem.

Comment: @barakmanos Well, it doesn't make much of a difference in this case, but if it was $33^{43}$ instead, $3^3$ is much easier than $33^3$ to calculate, once you've done the Euler's theorem reduction.

Comment: Yes, I agree (btw, you've got the exponent wrong in the comment above - should be $4$, not $3$).

Answer (score 1):

Go to the basics.

Let $(1! + 2! + 3! + 4! ........+ 1000!)=x$.

Now it is clear that unit digit of $x$ will be $3$. (Why??)

Also, If a number is divided by $10$, the remainder is the unit digit.

let us see what will be the unit digit of $x^{40}$.

Notice that unit digits of powers of $3$
 get repeated in pattern, as $3^0=1, 3^1=3, 3^2=9, 3^3=27$. Follow this pattern and you will find that unit digit of something like, $3^{40}$ will be $1$. I shall let you conclude now.